# Difference between curl and wsdl

Tags: curl

I try the command curl with specific port on HTTP URL `http://myurl:7000` and this works.

I try the same with wsdl but this time that doesn't work.

When I checked the firewall, I saw that the port 7000 was not open.

Why did the request work with curl without the correct port open in the firewall?

What's the difference between these commands?

Comment: What is `wsdl` in the context of this question?

Comment: Curl http://10.0.1.56:7000/bvs/services/TransactionService?wsdl --> ok     wsdlUrl=http://10.0.1.56:7000/bvs/services/TransactionService?wsdl --> nok  but works after opened the port in the firewall

Comment: Wsdl = web services description language it return a xml with description of a webservice

Comment: My interpretation of your posting was that you've used a command named `wsdl`. Then one could investigate differences in how `curl` and `wsdl` would work. If you actually mean WSDL (the interface description language) then this is another story.

Comment: Ok and what can explain that curl had works without the specific port open in the firewall ?